# Jenkins get user access Matrix

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I need to get users access matrix for **Jenkins** users using **Python**. What is endpoint for REST API ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

User matrix can be get by using {jenkins_url}/computer/(master)/config.xml request. After that you can parse it and create list of users with permissions.

Comment: That url does not seem to work. I got 400 bad request.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Jenkins REST API documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API):

> > Remote API can be used to do things like these:
>
> - retrieve information from Jenkins for programmatic consumption.
> - trigger a new build
> - create/copy jobs

To me, there is no way to access general jenkins configuration through REST API.

Trying to access https://your_jenkins:8080/manage/api failed:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /manage/api. Reason:

    Not Found
```

Comment: You can get it using  {jenkins_url}/computer/(master)/config.xml GET request with authorization.